# SVG with Webpacker

Tags: svg, webpacker

Is there a way to actually put an SVG file inline into my HTML from Webpacker?

I know I can do `<img src="<%= asset_pack_path 'media/svg/icon.svg' %>" />` but this outputs an image tag referencing an SVG. I would like the SVG to actually be in the code so I can style it with my styles.

Neil

Answer (score 1):

Was after the same thing, built a simple helper in rails to load the svg for me.

**1. Add this to your helpers folder:**

`helpers/svg_helper.svg`

```
module SvgHelper
  def show_svg(path)
    File.open("app/assets/images/#{path}", "rb") do |file|
      raw file.read
    end
  end
end
```

In my case I have my svgs under the image folder, but you can put it anywhere in assets.

**2. Then call it from your view.**

```
<%= show_svg('icons/icon-menu.svg') %>
```

Hope this helps!